# How does OpenCV VideoCapture determine CAP_PROP_FPS for HLS streams

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

Its quite clear how applications query OpenCV to get FPS for a Video source. There are [many](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-find-frame-rate-or-frames-per-second-fps-in-opencv-python-cpp/) examples online that show the [VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) call to get fps.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0);
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

However there are also may documented concerns that the accessed FPS can be inaccurate.

We are using ffmpeg to convert mp4 and avi files to HLS.

```
usr/bin/ffmpeg -i data/import/ParkingLot_20211028155745_snippet.mp4 -codec copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -framerate 15 -f hls data/fileServer/ParkingLot/ParkingLot_20211028155745_snippet.m3u8
```

We can then probe the HLS compliant output to see its attributes.

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams 'data/fileServer/ParkingLot/ParkingLot_20211028155745_snippet_0.ts' > thevideo.json 

more thevideo.json 
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "0/2",
            "codec_tag_string": "[27][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x001b",
            "width": 3840,
            "height": 2160,
            "coded_width": 3840,
            "coded_height": 2160,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuvj420p",
            "level": 51,
            "color_range": "pc",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "false",
            "nal_length_size": "0",
            "r_frame_rate": "15/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 126000,
            "start_time": "1.400000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "data/fileServer/ParkingLot/ParkingLot_20211028155745_snippet.m3u8",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 1,
        "format_name": "hls",
        "format_long_name": "Apple HTTP Live Streaming",
        "start_time": "1.400000",
        "duration": "29.400000",
        "size": "283",
        "bit_rate": "77",
        "probe_score": 100
    }
}
```

Here we see that the duration of the file is 29.4 (just under 30 seconds). We also see that r_frame_rate is 15/1. Its odd that the avg_frame_rate is 0/0.

We can also find the number of frames:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 data/fileServer/ParkingLot/ParkingLot_20211028155745_snippet.m3u8
```

The output is 440.

Though we seem to be setting FPS to 15, and this aligns with the actual number of frames in the file and its duration (29.4/440 = .0668 - 66.8 msec, or 14.96 FPS), VideoCapture (call to video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)) insists that the output frame rate is 30 FPS.

We are not sure how to invoke ffmpeg to ensure that it sets details that will allow OpenCV VideoCapture to see that the CAP_PROP_FPS is 15.

So our question is aimed both at the OpenCV community and the FFMPEG community (and even better someone who understands both).

What are the critical parameters to set in the creation of HLS compliant videos to ensure that OpenCV VideoCapture will see the FPS that was recorded into that video (15 FPS)?

Is VideoCapture assuming 30FPS by default, or is it actually computing that value through a look at the HLS stream?